# Creating Custom Web Service on Sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-foundation

I'm new to web services and i've been trying to create a custom one using this tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms464040.aspx

I've named my service as Files and created a new method on the webservice called UploadDocument:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string UploadDocument(string fileName, byte[] fileContents, string pathFolder)
    {
        if (fileContents == null)
        {
            return "Null Attachment";
        }

        try
        {
            int iStartIndex = pathFolder.LastIndexOf("/");
            string sitePath = pathFolder.Remove(iStartIndex);
            string folderName = pathFolder.Substring(iStartIndex + 1);

            SPSite site = new SPSite(sitePath);
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

            SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder(folderName);

            string fileURL = fileName;

            folder.Files.Add(fileURL, fileContents);

            if (folder.Files[fileURL].CheckedOutByUser.Name != "")
            {
                folder.Files[fileURL].CheckIn("File Checked In");
            }

            return "File added successfully!";

        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return "Error: " + ex.Source + " - " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

I've done exactly as it's listed there, all the same name, methods etc.. and when i get to the point where you're asked to create the application that's going to consume the web service, the tutorial gives the following lines:

```
ServiceFolder.Files myUploadService = new ServiceFolder.Files();
myUploadService .UseDefaultCredentials = true;
MessageBox.Show(myUploadService.HelloWorld());
```

but on my application, i can't call the web service as it's telling me to do, when i type

```
ServiceFolder.
```

it won't have the option to call the classes i've created. it only gives me some options that are not the ones listed on the tutorial:

```
ServiceFolder.FilesSoap (Interface)
ServiceFolder.FilesSoapChannel (Interface)
ServiceFolder.FilesSoapClient (Class)
ServiceFolder.UploadDocumentCompletedEventArgs (Class)
ServiceFolder.UploadDocumentRequest (Class)
ServiceFolder.UploadDocumentRequestBody (Class)
ServiceFolder.UploadDocumentResponse (Class)
ServiceFolder.UploadDocumentResponseBody (Class)
```

Am i missing something? doing something wrong? i've tried to recreate the service a couple times and always get the same thing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That walkthrough has some, er, issues...

I wrote a blog post with an alternate version that you may find a little easier to follow.

[Walkthrough: Creating a Custom ASP.NET (ASMX) Web Service in SharePoint 2010](http://msmvps.com/blogs/windsor/archive/2011/11/04/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-asp-net-asmx-web-service-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: Rob..

i don't have words to express how grateful i am for this walkthrough.

Just one little question.

How do you invoke the GetSiteListCount() method in your site/application? I've added the service reference, but i can't find how to call that method and use it's result on my code.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I've updated the blog post to demonstrate how to create a client for the service.

Comment: Rob. It worked like a charm. Thank so you much for your help.