# High Trust Provider-Hosted apps on cloudshare

Tags: sharepoint-addin, 401, provider-hosted-app

I do not have sufficient resources to create my own SharePoint 2013 farm and hence started using the trial environment from CloudShare (http://www.cloudshare.com).

I wanted to get a hands-on on high-trust provider hosted apps. I created an app based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179901(office.15).aspx. But after hitting F5 button and navigating to the site I'm encountering

> 401 Unauthorized exception

Tried all steps mentioned in [Getting 401/403 in High Trust App for Sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79284/getting-401-403-in-high-trust-app-for-sharepoint-2013) but still getting the same error. I can't figure out what is missing here.

Does anybody have experience creating a high-trust app in cloudshare? If so, could you please share your knowledge on the errors and how it was resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this walkthrough, it's far more detailed than the one on MSDN.

[Configuring High Trust Apps for SharePoint 2013](http://www.binarywave.com/blogs/eshupps/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=267)

Comment: I know you have been around a while, and surely there is a reason behind you just leaving the link as an answer? I would love it if you made you answer less dependent on the link (if the link breaks, your answer will not be helpful) :)

Comment: By providing a link to a more detailed walkthrough I'm trying to help Victor determine where the issue lies. I could go though the MSDN walkthrough and compare it to the one I linked and then try to deduce where the possible sources of confusion could lie but that would reduce Victors opportunity to learn from the experience which is what his stated goal is.

Comment: To me, that should be more of a comment on his post than an answer then

Comment: I appreciate you contributing, Rob! Although, I think its recognized that links should be an additive or an afterthought. Links as answers, although helpful, does not provide a direct solution to the question at hand.

Comment: The poster states, "I wanted to get a hands-on on high-trust provider hosted apps". The poster also states that he used a walkthrough on MSDN to try to learn how to achieve his goal but things didn't work. I think that the poster will have a better chance at learning how to achieve his goal by going through the walkthrough that I linked. IMHO, the information in the linked blog post represents a complete answer to original question.

Comment: BTW, here's an example of a question that I answered in a similar fashion. It was marked as correct and has so far received five up-votes. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22724/creating-custom-web-service-on-sharepoint-2010/22743